# Access Files inside xlam Addin

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen that xlam files contain directories etc. (I have unpacked it via 7Zip)
Is it possible to store files inside of a xlam file and access those from vba?
I was thinking to store a somewhat larger PowerShell script or an executable inside of the xlam file and then access it from vba. Is this possible and how can I define the path to the script/file?

Comment: If someone would actually use a xlam file to troyan horse me with an executable I would kill him. I would stay away from that. If Microsoft isn't that stupid they would consider any files that include something irregular as not valid. Anyway here is the documentation: [Understanding the Open XML file formats)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/understanding-the-open-xml-file-formats)

Comment: While it may not be useful in your case, it is possible to unhide a worksheet in an .xlam file, store information on it, hide it again and then use this information with vb.